Не удается добавить свое разрешение в Ubuntu 24.04
У меня два монитора, где то дня 3 назад компьютер выключил командой poweroff, там что то у меня заглючило и я выключил через кнопку, на след.день я включаю комп, убунту не видит 2 монитор, и разрешение на основном 640x480, а мне надо 1920х1080
В настройках нету смены разрешения, делал через терминал с xrandr, но когда меняю разрешение, вылазит ошибка
У меня также стоит винда, но когда загружаюсь на нее, то все окей, работает четко, а на убунту вот такая ошибка

Проблему решил, помог мне ChatGPT)
Как оказалось, у меня было очень много не обновленных пакетов
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
И после этого нужно перезапустить X-сервер, чтобы обновить конфигурацию
sudo systemctl restart gdm - для GNOME
sudo systemctl restart lightdm - для LightDM

Для начала
dpkg-configure -a
apt -f install


Сделал, все также вылазит ошибка

Могло помочь... Ну значит что-то ещё
